# Input field glitching out in table

Tags: html, css

I created php scirpt to generate a table with headers and inputs.
It is some kind of form but the problem is that input field are
(around) 5px out of the table. I think it is the best to show it
on screenshot.

[image]

Code:

```css
:root {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.form-block-inputs {
  display: grid;
}

.no_m {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.alert {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  /* border-radius: 10px; */
  border: 4px solid #ff1a1a;
}

.sucess {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  margin: 10px;
  /* border-radius: 10px; */
  border: 4px solid #038f5b;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Some really random title that don't have any meaning</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="http://localhost/app/?logout=true">Wylogój</a>

  <div style="display: grid;">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>NR</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".OLT_MYSZYNIEC"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>LIT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>MUFA</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".OLT"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>UWAGI</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>TUBY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>DATA1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".2021-08-13"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>DATA2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".2021-08-13"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SPAWY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".120"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SP.DAC</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>LOG</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ODW</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".ND"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SPL 1X4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SPL 1X8</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SPL 1X16</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>AD.SIMP</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>AD.DUPL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>PIGTAIL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>OLT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>NEXT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ODN 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ODN 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ODN 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D30</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D50</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D80</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D100</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D120</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D150</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>MAŁPKI</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Anyone know a way to fix it?
PS: I used `width: 100%;` on inputs so they will take up whole row in table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra width is due to the default padding and border of the `<input>` box.

Set these to `0` to remove them and the input will be inside the table cell's borders.

```css
td input {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
:root {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.form-block-inputs {
  display: grid;
}

.no_m {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.alert {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
  color: white;
  margin: 10px;
  /* border-radius: 10px; */
  border: 4px solid #ff1a1a;
}

.sucess {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  margin: 10px;
  /* border-radius: 10px; */
  border: 4px solid #038f5b;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Some really random title that don't have any meaning</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="http://localhost/app/?logout=true">Wylogój</a>

  <div style="display: grid;">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>NR</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".OLT_MYSZYNIEC"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>LIT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>MUFA</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".OLT"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>UWAGI</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>TUBY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>DATA1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".2021-08-13"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>DATA2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".2021-08-13"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SPAWY</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".120"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SP.DAC</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>LOG</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ODW</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value=".ND"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SPL 1X4</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SPL 1X8</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SPL 1X16</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>AD.SIMP</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>AD.DUPL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>PIGTAIL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>OLT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>NEXT</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ODN 1</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ODN 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>ODN 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D30</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D50</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D80</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D100</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D120</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>D150</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>MAŁPKI</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input style="width: 100%;" type="text" value="."></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```